# How to add using directive to scriptblock executed as a thread job?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, powershell-core

I was wondering if there's any way of passing a using directive into a script block executed by Start-ThreadJob. If you run the below code, the invoke line works, but the job returns an 'unable to find type' error:

```
using namespace System.IO

function dothis {
    return {
        [Path]::Combine("this", "that")
    }
}

$sb = dothis
$sb.Invoke()

$job = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock $sb
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

We can't add the directive inside the script block (we get 'A using statement must appear before any other statements in a script') and none of the parameters for Start-ThreadJob seem to accept this type of thing. The only way to get around this is have fully qualified type names inside the script block:

```
[System.Path.IO]::Combine("this", "that")
```

Fine for this example, but very messy and cumbersome when you're working with a type a lot, or a lot of different types within your script block. Does anyone know of a neater way to get around this issue?

Comment: Linked answer should answer this. TL;DR: you shouldnt do this.

Comment: yep I had hoped to avoid using fully qualified type names for reasons stated in the question. nm, seems it's not possible to avoid

Comment: The workaround is there in the linked answer but I certainly would not recommend you to use it.